# "Convert" FoxPro prg query for use with SQL

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports, linked-server, foxpro, visual-foxpro

I have several FoxPro prg's that have been in use for many years. Now we are slowly trying to implement the use of SQL Server and I'm trying to implement that with the prg's. I have created 2 linked servers to the .dbf files that we are using and that all works great. Now I'm trying to figure out how to convert, or translate, the prg code so I can use it in a Crystal Reports query. I know the basic SQL queries and if I test  the linked servers with a simple query it all works fine in Crystal. But some of the prg's are quite complex and use cursors, and that's what I'm struggeling with. Here is an example:

```
Select soheader.partno As Item,;
soheader.sono As sono,;
soheader.rev As sorev,;
soheader.sqty As sqty,;
soheader.need_date As needdate,;
soheader.priority,;
soheader.salesno,;
soheader.crea_date,;
soheader.start_date,;
soheader.remark1,;
soheader.remark2,;
soheader.instr1,;
soheader.instr2,;
soheader.plandate,;
soheader.rev,;
soheader.fgloc,;
soheader.mtlloc,;
soheader.solineno,;
soheader.Userid,;
soheader.part_desc,;
Soroute.opno As routeopno,;
Soroute.loadcenter,;
Soroute.Descrip As Routedes,;
Immaster.misc04 As lottrack,;
immaster.upccode As upccode;
FROM soheader Inner Join Soroute On soheader.sono = Soroute.sono;
LEFT Join immaster On soheader.partno = immaster.Item;
Into Cursor c1

Select c1.*,;
    Somater.partno As partno,;
    STR(Asc(Somater.Phanref),3)As Phanref,;
    STR(Asc(Somater.Phanid),3)As Phanid,;
    VAL(Somater.qty_assy) As qty_assy,;
    VAL(Somater.qty_aloc) As qty_aloc,;
    Somater.Delmark As Delmark;
    FROM c1 Left Join Somater On c1.sono = Somater.sono And c1.routeopno = Somater.opno;
    INTO Cursor c2


Select c2.*,;
    immaster.Descrip As Descrip,;
    immaster.stockum As stockum,;
    immaster.misc04 As misc04,;
    immaster.lotstat As lotstat;
    FROM c2 Left Join immaster On c2.partno = immaster.Item;
    Into Cursor c3

Select c3.*,;
    imstock.lonhand As lotqty,;
    imstock.locid As lotloc,;
    imstock.lot As lotnum;
    FROM c3 Left Join imstock On imstock.Item = c3.partno AND c3.mtlloc = imstock.locid;
    Into Cursor c4 

Select c4.*, Iif(Empty(Bmrev.fgparent), Bmrev.itemparent, Bmrev.fgparent ) As fg;
    FROM c4 Left Join Bmrev On c4.Item + c4.sorev = Bmrev.itemparent + Bmrev.rev;
    into Cursor C5

Select C5.*, bmsl.findno, bmsl.scrpad;
    FROM C5 Left Join bmsl On C5.fg + C5.partno + C5.sorev = bmsl.itemparent + bmsl.itemchild + bmsl.rev;
    INTO Cursor C6
```

How do I deal with the different cursors in SQL so I get the correct end result?

EDIT:

After some great help from David we have come to a point where the query works, but now there is an issue with the conversion from varchar to bigint. I have changed the query to get rid of a couple of issues and here is the current query:

```
    SELECT
    SOH.partno AS Item
    ,SOH.sono AS sono
    ,SOH.rev AS sorev
    ,SOH.sqty AS sqty
    ,SOH.need_date AS needdate
    ,SOH.priority
    ,SOH.salesno
    ,SOH.crea_date
    ,SOH.start_date
    ,SOH.remark1
    ,SOH.remark2
    ,SOH.instr1
    ,SOH.instr2
    ,SOH.plandate
    ,SOH.rev
    ,SOH.fgloc
    ,SOH.mtlloc
   ,SOH.solineno
    ,SOH.Userid
    ,SOH.part_desc
    ,SOR.opno AS routeopno
    ,SOR.loadcenter
    ,SOR.Descrip AS Routedes
    ,SO.partno AS partno
    ,STR(ASCII(SO.Phanref), 3) AS Phanref
    ,STR(ASCII(SO.Phanid), 3) AS Phanid
    ,(
         CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(SO.qty_assy) = 1
             THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL, SO.qty_assy)
             ELSE NULL
         END
    ) AS qty_assy
    ,(
         CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(SO.qty_aloc) = 1
             THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL, SO.qty_aloc)
             ELSE NULL
         END
    ) AS qty_aloc
    ,SO.Delmark AS Delmark
    ,IMM.misc04 AS lottrack
    ,IMM.upccode AS upccode
    ,IMM.Descrip AS Descrip
    ,IMM.stockum AS stockum
    ,IMM.misc04 AS misc04
    ,IMM.lotstat AS lotstat
    ,IMS.lonhand AS lotqty
    ,IMS.locid AS lotloc
   ,IMS.lot AS lotnum
    ,(
         CASE WHEN ISNULL(BMR.fgparent, 0) = 0
             THEN BMR.itemparent
             ELSE BMR.fgparent
         END
    ) AS fg
    ,BMS.findno
    ,BMS.scrpad
FROM [LinkedWS]...[Soheader] AS SOH
INNER JOIN [LinkedWS]...[Soroute] AS SOR
    ON SOH.sono = SOR.sono
LEFT OUTER JOIN [LinkedAC]...[immaster] AS IMM
    ON SOH.partno = IMM.Item
LEFT OUTER JOIN [LinkedWS]...[Somater] AS SO
    ON 1 = 1
       AND SOH.sono = SO.sono
       AND SOR.opno = SO.opno
LEFT OUTER JOIN [LinkedAC]...[imstock] AS IMS
    ON 1 = 1
       AND SOH.partno = IMS.item
       AND SOH.mtlloc = IMS.locid
LEFT OUTER JOIN [LinkedWS]...[Bmrev] AS BMR
    ON SOH.partno + SOH.rev = BMR.itemparent + BMR.rev
LEFT OUTER JOIN [LinkedWS]...[bmsl] AS BMS
    ON (
           CASE WHEN ISNULL(BMR.fgparent, 0) = 0
               THEN BMR.itemparent
               ELSE BMR.fgparent
           END
       ) + SO.partno + SOH.rev = BMS.itemparent + BMS.itemchild + BMS.rev
```

When I run this query I get the error that it can't convert the varchar to bigint. If I change bigint to int, I get an error "Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '       0.350' to data type int."
The fields qty_assy and qty_aloc are both character fields in the FoxPro tables, but as far as I was able to tell there are no characters in those fields. The leading spaces in front of the 0.350 though lead me to believe that I need to maybe add a TRIM to get rid of them?

EDIT 2:

Changed the conversion from BIGINT to DECIMAL and that solved the issue. I'm still getting one error message  but that doesn't seem to affect anything. Problem solved!

Comment: Based on the foxpro code it looks like you need to use SQL sub query. If you post some sample data and what the expected result is, Someone on the forum may be able to generate sample SQL code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cursors represent temporary tables (for more information check [this article](http://www.alvechurchdata.co.uk/company/fox-cursor.html)).

The translated code for SQL Server will look like the following:

```
SELECT
    SOH.partno AS Item
    ,SOH.sono AS sono
    ,SOH.rev AS sorev
    ,SOH.sqty AS sqty
    ,SOH.need_date AS needdate
    ,SOH.priority
    ,SOH.salesno
    ,SOH.crea_date
    ,SOH.start_date
    ,SOH.remark1
    ,SOH.remark2
    ,SOH.instr1
    ,SOH.instr2
    ,SOH.plandate
    ,SOH.rev
    ,SOH.fgloc
    ,SOH.mtlloc
    ,SOH.solineno
    ,SOH.Userid
    ,SOH.part_desc
    ,SOR.opno AS routeopno
    ,SOR.loadcenter
    ,SOR.Descrip AS Routedes
    ,SO.partno AS partno
    ,STR(ASCII(SO.Phanref), 3) AS Phanref
    ,STR(ASCII(SO.Phanid), 3) AS Phanid
    ,IIF(ISNUMERIC(SO.qty_assy) = 1, CONVERT(BIGINT, SO.qty_assy), NULL) AS qty_assy
    ,IIF(ISNUMERIC(SO.qty_aloc) = 1, CONVERT(BIGINT, SO.qty_aloc), NULL) AS qty_aloc
    ,SO.Delmark AS Delmark
    ,IMM.misc04 AS lottrack
    ,IMM.upccode AS upccode
    ,IMM.Descrip AS Descrip
    ,IMM.stockum AS stockum
    ,IMM.misc04 AS misc04
    ,IMM.lotstat AS lotstat
    ,IMS.lonhand AS lotqty
    ,IMS.locid AS lotloc
    ,IMS.lot AS lotnum
    ,IIF(ISNULL(BMR.fgparent, 0) = 0, BMR.itemparent, BMR.fgparent) AS fg
    ,BMS.findno
    ,BMS.scrpad
FROM Soheader AS SOH
INNER JOIN Soroute AS SOR
    ON SOH.sono = SOR.sono
LEFT OUTER JOIN immaster AS IMM
    ON SOH.partno = IMM.Item
LEFT OUTER JOIN Somater AS SO
    ON 1 = 1
       AND SOH.sono = SO.sono
       AND SOR.opno = SO.opno
LEFT OUTER JOIN imstock AS IMS
    ON 1 = 1
       AND SOH.partno = IMS.Item
       AND SOH.mtlloc = IMS.locid
LEFT OUTER JOIN Bmrev AS BMR
    ON SOH.Item + SOH.sorev = BMR.itemparent + BMR.rev
LEFT OUTER JOIN bmsl AS BMS
    ON IIF(ISNULL(BMR.fgparent, 0) = 0, BMR.itemparent, BMR.fgparent) + SO.partno + SOH.sorev = BMS.itemparent + BMS.itemchild + BMS.rev
```

I've guessed that the fgparent column has numeric data type and that why the line

```
Empty(Bmrev.fgparent)
```

has been translated to

```
ISNULL(BMR.fgparent, 0) = 0
```

In case that it's alphanumeric, the conversion can be changed based on the information provided in [this link](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/advantage9.1/empty.htm).

Equivalence of the functions

```
FoxPro SQL      SQL SERVER
----------------------------
STR             STR
ASC             ASCII
VAL             CONVERT(BIGINT, ...)
IIF             IIF
```

Useful links:

- [Visual FoxPro functions for numbers](http://www.alvechurchdata.co.uk/foxnumber.htm)
- [STR (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189527.aspx)
- [ASCII (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177545.aspx)
- [CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)
- [IIF (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx)

**EDIT**

Check the below code if you want to use [CASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) instead of [IFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx)

```
SELECT
    SOH.partno AS Item
    ,SOH.sono AS sono
    ,SOH.rev AS sorev
    ,SOH.sqty AS sqty
    ,SOH.need_date AS needdate
    ,SOH.priority
    ,SOH.salesno
    ,SOH.crea_date
    ,SOH.start_date
    ,SOH.remark1
    ,SOH.remark2
    ,SOH.instr1
    ,SOH.instr2
    ,SOH.plandate
    ,SOH.rev
    ,SOH.fgloc
    ,SOH.mtlloc
    ,SOH.solineno
    ,SOH.Userid
    ,SOH.part_desc
    ,SOR.opno AS routeopno
    ,SOR.loadcenter
    ,SOR.Descrip AS Routedes
    ,SO.partno AS partno
    ,STR(ASCII(SO.Phanref), 3) AS Phanref
    ,STR(ASCII(SO.Phanid), 3) AS Phanid
    ,(
         CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(SO.qty_assy) = 1
             THEN CONVERT(BIGINT, SO.qty_assy)
             ELSE NULL
         END
    ) AS qty_assy
    ,(
         CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(SO.qty_aloc) = 1
             THEN CONVERT(BIGINT, SO.qty_aloc)
             ELSE NULL
         END
    ) AS qty_aloc
    ,SO.Delmark AS Delmark
    ,IMM.misc04 AS lottrack
    ,IMM.upccode AS upccode
    ,IMM.Descrip AS Descrip
    ,IMM.stockum AS stockum
    ,IMM.misc04 AS misc04
    ,IMM.lotstat AS lotstat
    ,IMS.lonhand AS lotqty
    ,IMS.locid AS lotloc
    ,IMS.lot AS lotnum
    ,(
         CASE WHEN ISNULL(BMR.fgparent, 0) = 0
             THEN BMR.itemparent
             ELSE BMR.fgparent
         END
    ) AS fg
    ,BMS.findno
    ,BMS.scrpad
FROM Soheader AS SOH
INNER JOIN Soroute AS SOR
    ON SOH.sono = SOR.sono
LEFT OUTER JOIN immaster AS IMM
    ON SOH.partno = IMM.Item
LEFT OUTER JOIN Somater AS SO
    ON 1 = 1
       AND SOH.sono = SO.sono
       AND SOR.opno = SO.opno
LEFT OUTER JOIN imstock AS IMS
    ON 1 = 1
       AND SOH.partno = IMS.Item
       AND SOH.mtlloc = IMS.locid
LEFT OUTER JOIN Bmrev AS BMR
    ON SOH.Item + SOH.sorev = BMR.itemparent + BMR.rev
LEFT OUTER JOIN bmsl AS BMS
    ON (
           CASE WHEN ISNULL(BMR.fgparent, 0) = 0
               THEN BMR.itemparent
               ELSE BMR.fgparent
           END
       ) + SO.partno + SOH.sorev = BMS.itemparent + BMS.itemchild + BMS.rev
```

Comment: David, that is an excellent answer. I will need to go over it tomorrow so I can (hopefully) understand it and test it. Thanks for all the resource links as well! I will get back to you in the next day or two once I've had time to go over it.

Comment: David, I finally found some time to check out your answer. I think I understand most of it, but there are some issues I need help with. First of all, I'm on SQL Express and the IIF statements are not supported. SO I looked into the CASE statments and I'm a bit unclear as to how the syntax would go for ,IIF(ISNUMERIC(SO.qty_assy) = 1, CONVERT(BIGINT, SO.qty_assy), NULL) AS qty_assy I'm also getting syntax errors for all the "=" operators but I haven't been able to figure out why that is. Any suggestions?

Comment: David, it's looking much better now. I see what you did with the IIF statements. Unfortunately now I get an error message saying:"Error converting data type varchar to bigint". I will have to check which conversion it chokes on and then double check the links you provided.

Comment: The error is probably because the content of the column `qty_assy` or /and `qty_aloc` contain non numeric data.

Comment: Most likely, I will confirm that when I get a chance to look at the tables. Thanks for all the help so far!

Comment: David, please see the edit to the original question. Still trying to figure out the conversion issue but the query itself should be correct.

Comment: Sorry to see your edits late but I'm glad that your problem is solved :).

Answer (score 0):

Another shortcut for staying similar with VFP cursors is to have your SQL stored procedure (or whatever) use temp tables via "#Cursor".  The syntax is very similar for you to play with

```
select a.*
   into #C_TempCursorInSQL
   from blah a
   where conditions..

select b.*
   into #C_AnotherCursor
   from #C_TempCursorInSQL b
   where otherConditions...
```

etc..  So you can still try to keep the parallels going with queries and working small pieces at a time.